# How does the Windows 10 linux implementation compare to Vagrant?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, vagrant

I've used Vagrant on a Mac environment (as a novice) that seemed to create a virtual Linux machine accessible via terminal. I used to develop in an open-environment on a mac, and was wondering if I could create a similar environment in Windows.

My idea at the time was to install a Vagrant on Windows, which gives access to your file system via a Linux shell. For all intents and purposes the Windows 10 implementation of bash looks exactly the same.

What is the difference in this use case?

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_%28software%29) is an open-source tool for deploying VM's.

[Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about) (WSL) is a new kernel & OS infrastructure that allows Windows to load and run native, unmodified Linux command-line tools, apps, and binaries within/from a Linux-compatible environment/shell.